# How do I add a message if a value is out of range in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

If I have the following:

```
[Range(0,120)]
public int QtyOnHand { get; set; }
```

How can I add an error message to say the required range?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `RangeAttribute` has an `ErrorMessage` that you can set:

```
[Range (0, 120, ErrorMessage = "Quantity on hand must be between {1} and {2}.")]
public int QtyOnHand { get; set; }
```

By using `{1}` and `{2}`, you don't have to keep changing the string when your numbers change. `{0}` is for the name of the field.  This can be accompanied with the `DisplayNameAttribute` as such:

```
[DisplayName ("Quantity on Hand")]
[Range (0, 120, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
public int QtyOnHand { get; set; }
```

Comment: +1 for learning something new on formatting error messages today

Answer (score 3):

`[Range(0,120,ErrorMessage="The quantity on hand must be between 0 and 120")]`

Answer (score 2):

`[Range(0, 120,ErrorMessage="The Qty Available must be between 0 and 120.")]`

Make sure unobtrusive javascript is enabled for client-side validation.

reference: http://rachelappel.com/building-a-relational-data-model-in-asp.net-mvc-3-w-ef-code-first